# Модификация страницы редактирования записи в django

Tags: python, django-admin

В джанго есть админка, которая позволяет редактировать записи в БД, она генерируется автоматически. В моей модели есть поле TextField, мне надо добавить markdown редактор на страничку с добавлением/редактированием записи для этого поля.

Как это возможно сделать? Видел только варианты полного изменения всей страницы, но хочется обойтись малой кровью

PS как добавить markdown editor в моем случае - добавить  на старницу

Comment: Заменить виджет поля формы модели на желаемый https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176613

Comment: Спасибо, получилось пройти по этому пути

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Добавить виджет редактора

   ```
   pipenv install django-mdeditor
   # or
   pip install django-mdeditor
   ```
2. Зарегистрировать виджет

   ```
   INSTALLED_APPS = [
       ...
       'mdeditor',
   ]
   ```
3. Добавить в `admin.py`

   ```
   @admin.register(Post)
   class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   formfield_overrides = {
       models.TextField: {'widget': MDEditorWidget}
   }
   ```

Это сделает для всех полей типа `TextField` модели `Post` редактируемые поля в виде markdown редактора на основе ckeditor. [Все это отсюда](https://pypi.org/project/django-mdeditor/)

Единственное, что там с русским языком не все ок, в некоторых местах китайский вылезает